# A minimization problem in function fitting setup

Tags: functional-analysis, real-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\Omega$ be a convex, closed, compact set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with a smooth boundary.

Given a data $(x_i,d_i)$, $x_i \in \Omega$,$d_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $i = 1,2,3...N$, $N>d$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N d_i = 0$. Also given that, there are always $d$ vectors in $\{x_i\}$ which are linearly independent.

Let $A = \int_{\Omega}dx$

I want to find a continuous function $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, such that,

1. $\int_{\Omega}f(x)dx = 0$ and
2. $C(f)$ is minimum, where $$C(f) = \frac{A^{1/d}}{N}\bigg(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N |f(x_i)-d_i|^d\bigg)^{1/d} +\|f\|_{L^d}+ A^{1/d} \||\nabla f|\|_{L^d}$$

Does the solution exist? Is the solution unique? I mean any two solutions are equal almost everywhere?

Comment: If I understand correctly the problem, when $d>1$, the infimum of $C(f)$ among the mean-vanishing continuous functions on $\Omega$ is $0$, and it is not attained, because one can always find a continuous function  $f$, with $\int_\Omega f dx=0$, with arbitrarily small  $V_\Omega(f)+\|f\|_1$, and with $f(x_i)=d_i$ for $i=1,\dots,N$.

Comment: @PietroMajer : When you don't allow jump discontinuties (as $f$ supposed to be continuous), then I am not sure, or atleast its no trivial for me, that you can construct such a function which concentrates on the data points. ...

Comment: ...For example in 2 dimensions, consider a bump around a data point,and if the bump keeps shrinking (like $f(\alpha x)$, $\alpha$ increasing, the support vanishes, hence L1 norm vanishes, but the variation of bump goes to $\infty$ if we shrink the bump. So i dont have any suitable example to prove that. But if you consider disks (like step functions) around data points and make their circumpherence goes to zero by shrinking them, they the minimum value can be arbitrarily small, but here such discs are not continuous functions.

Comment: In dimension $2$, a bump supported on a disk $B_r$ of radius $r$ (so area $O(r^2)$), and of height $1$, has gradient of size $1/r$, so doesn't it gives a variation $\int_{B_r}|\nabla f(x)|dx=O( r)$?

Comment: @PietroMajer : Replacing $$C(f) = \frac{\int_{\Omega}dx}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^N |f(x_i)-d_i| +\|f\|_{L^1}+V_{\Omega}(f)$$, by $$C(f) = \frac{\int_{\Omega}dx}{N}\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^N |f(x_i)-d_i|^d\}^{1/d} +\|f\|_{L^d}+ \||\nabla f|\|_{L^d}$$ Its still the same for $d=1$ but for higher dimensions I am hoping it generalizes well without giving any trivial solutions (I need to prove/verify this) like infimum being zero.

Comment: Note however that in the modified problem, for $N=2$, say with $d_1=-d_2>0$, even if the infimum is not $0$, it should not be attained, and the minimization should produce concentration at $x_1$ and $x_2$, because any $C(f)$ can be improved, shrinking $f_+$ towards a delta around $x_1$ and  $f_-$ towards a bump around $x_2$.

Comment: @PietroMajer : Concentrating on data points, does not mean the third term is the minimum possible, while first two terms are. Take for example, in the 1-d case, it does not concentrate on data points because the third term need not attain minimum possible, as ($2\sum |d_i|$) need not be the minimum possible value for third term, while the first two terms are going towards minimum possible. (=0).

Comment: As a side note : I am not bothered about attaining the minimum possible always, converging towards it is fine. But I don't want the function to concentrate around data points while doing so, as this gives a trivial and bad function.

Comment: @PietroMajer : What is the difference between shrinking towards a delta and shrinking towards a bump, you mean on one you shrink only one dimension and on the other you shrink both dimensions? Are you considering only two points? or Do you imply it can be for any arbitrary number of points whose values necessarily need not be all same?

Comment: I guess the number of data points need to be greater than the number of dimensions?

Comment: @PietroMajer : If you shrink a two dimensional bump along only one dimension, the $L^2$ norm of its gradient grows.

Comment: @PietroMajer : Do you still see any pit falls in this generalization for higher dimensions. What do you think usefulness of 1-d case? (if you keep aside higher dimensions) Appreciate your valuble comments and feedback which is of immense use to me.

Comment: The OP asked to have this migrated to Math.SE.

Comment: Just some speculation: with $\Omega = [0,1], (x_1,d_1) = (0,-1), (x_2,d_2) = (1,1)$, I'm guessing that we "want" the solution to be some linear function $g(x) = a + bx$, with $b > 0$ and $a < 0$. But this can be improved upon: let $f(0) = g(0)$ and $f(1) = g(1)$, but have $f$ grow with rate $k$ on $[0,-g(0)/k]$ and $[1 - g(1)/k,0]$, and 0 otherwise --- this improves the second term in $C(f)$, while the 3rd term stays constant, so $f$ will concentrate as $k$ grows.

Comment: @svangen : Thanks for the good comment. Move those points a little interior, say one at $\delta$ and other at $1-\delta$ we see the function spreads in $(0,\delta)$ and $(1-\delta,1)$.

Comment: @svengen : and I am not particularly restricting for anything linear only. I haven't stated so either.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju I've tried to elaborate the idea in an answer. Even if we move the points to the interior, we can always improve $f$ on $(\delta,1-\delta)$, no matter what it does outside that interval. (The answer is slightly more complicated because in the case of larger $N$, the global constraint $\int_\Omega f dx = 0$ can require the solution to be non-monotone on the interval where we are trying to improve it).

Comment: @svangen : Hi, I am not contradicting with what happens in $(\delta,1-\delta)$, I mean to say its not going to zero outside that is in $(0,\delta)$ and $(1-\delta,1)$. I mean the solution need not always trivially concentrate only on data points and zero else where,  in a general case. The solution is still useful to me.

Comment: Well, there will not exist an optimal solution (since any candidate can be improved on $(\delta,1-\delta)$). But also, if you give me any candidate function $g$, I can improve on it with the similar trick that will make $g \rightarrow 0$ also on "outside" intervals $(0,\delta)$ and $(1-\delta,1)$.

Comment: Can't there be a function with jump discontinuties, that is optimal? I am confused what you are trying to say? If we allow jumps, still there cant be an optimal solution?

Comment: @svangen : C(f) is a semi norm, so there definitely an optimum solution, the question is in which space it lies?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57884/discussion-between-svangen-and-rajesh-dachiraju).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quick answer to your question (for $d > 1$) is no, there is no continuous solution. This can be rectified, however, by using a different $L^p$ norm.

Starting with the case of the $L^d$ norm as asked in the question, where $d$ is also the dimension of the Euclidean space, consider the following. For any $x_0\in\Omega$ and real numbers $r_0,A > 0$, define $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb R$ by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,&{\rm if\ }r\ge r_0,\\
1,&{\rm if\ }r\le e^{-A}r_0,\\
A^{-1}\log(r_0/r)&{\rm if\ }e^{-A}r_0 < r < r_0
\end{cases}
$$
where $r=\lVert x-x_0\rVert_2$. The norm $\lVert f\rVert_{L^d}$ is bounded by $cr_0$ for constant $c$, so can be made small by taking $r_0$ to be small. Also, $\nabla f$ is of magnitude $1/(Ar)$ for $e^{-A}r_0 < r < r_0$. So (for some other constant $c$),
\begin{align}
\lVert\nabla f\rVert_{L^d}^d&=c\int_{e^{-A}r_0}^{r_0}(Ar)^{-d}\,(r^{d-1}dr)\\
&=cA^{-d}\left[\log r\right]_{e^{-A}r_0}^{r_0}=cA^{-(d-1)}
\end{align}
So, by taking $A$ large and $r_0$ small, we can make $\lVert f\rVert_{L^d}$ and $\lVert\nabla f\rVert_{L^d}$ as small as we like, with $f(x_0)=1$. By taking linear combinations of such functions (with $x_0$ replaced by the $x_i$ in the question, $C(f)$ can be made arbitrarily small. Clearly, the limit $C(f)=0$ is not obtained by a continuous function.

Instead, consider using the following for $C(f)$,
$$
C(f)=a\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\lvert f(x_i)-d_i\rvert^p\right)^{1/p}+b\lVert f\rVert_{L^p}+c\lVert\nabla f\rVert_{L^p}  \tag1
$$
for any positive constants $a,b,c$ and $p > d$. The [Sobolev embedding theorem and Morrey's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sobolev_inequality&oldid=777853880#Morrey.27s_inequality) bounds the $C^{0,\alpha}$-norm of $f$ by a positive multiple of $C(f)$, with $\alpha=1-\frac dp$. This guarantees that the limit of any sequence of continuous $f_n\colon\Omega\to\mathbb R$ with $C(f_n)$ bounded is, at the very least, $\alpha$-Hölder continuous. Any sequence $f_n$ with $C(f_n)$ converging to $\inf\{C(f)\colon \int f=0\}$ satisfies
$$
a\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\lvert f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)\rvert^p\right)^{1/p}+b\lVert f_n-f\rVert_{L^p}+c\lVert\nabla(f_n-f)\rVert_{L^p}\to0 \tag2
$$
where $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is the unique continuous function minimising $C(f)$. The convergence of $f_n$ and the existence and uniqueness of the limit $f$ follows from [uniform convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space) of the $L^p$ norm for $1 < p < \infty$.

Comment: I have a confusion. The norm $\||\nabla f|\|_{L^d}$ I have been using is not quite the Sobolev norm, if you had mistaken for it. I take the magnitude of gradient and then take the L^d norm, which is different from Sobolev norm.

Comment: George, Can you please clarify?

Comment: As all norms on $\mathbb R^d$ are equivalent, what you have is equivalent.

Comment: sounds great! I like the example you have provided. By making the transition steeper and perimeter going to zero, you can trick the $L^d$ norm to zero, but can be avoided by  going for a higher norm. But I wouldnt want to go any further than $L^{d+1}$ norm.

Comment: The limit will in fact be Lipschitz, by looking at the PDE implied by your minimisation problem

Comment: $d$ being odd is very interesting. the new $C(f)$ is differentiable, if we parameterize $f$, say to be a trigonometric polynomial. I mean if $f$ is band limited!

Comment: George : Could you please state the implied pde for this problem, with your new modification to $d+1$?

Comment: I can when I log on later

Comment: cool, that would be great. Thanks for the nice answer.

Comment: I get the pde $\lVert f\rVert_{L^p}^{-(p-1)}{\rm sgn}(f)\lvert f\rvert^{p-1}-\lVert\nabla f\rVert_{L^p}^{-(p-1)}\nabla\cdot\left(\lVert\nabla f\rVert_2^{p-2}\nabla f\right)=\lambda$
away from the points $x_i$, for a constant $\lambda$. This implies that $\nabla\cdot\left(\lVert\nabla f\rVert_2^{p-2}\nabla f\right)$ is continuous. I thought that this would enough to bound $\nabla f$, but am not so sure now.

Comment: Hi George, If the data is originating from a continuously differentiable function $g$, (also being in normed spaces as required by the problem) and the data points are a countable dense subset of $\Omega$, Is it possible to prove that $f_{min}$ is same as $g$?

Comment: I mean in the limit of data increasing and tending to become a countable dense subset, does $f_{min} \to g$?

Comment: I am interested in proving that $f_{min}$ is atleast lipschitz. Could you please suggest any hints/clues or approaches.

Comment: We havent levaraged the fact that $f_{min}$ is a minimum.

Comment: You said the pde is equal to $\lambda$ away from $x_i$. What is its value on points $x_i$? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Could you please write out the detailed proof of the existence of a continuous function $f \ni C(f)=\inf\{C(f)\}$? You claim that the existence of such a continuous function follows from the uniform convexity of $L^p$. It is not clear to me why. In addition, given that such continuous $f$ exists, it is not clear to me why your statement regarding Equation (2) should hold, if $f\ne0$. You seem to claim $\|f_n\|\rightarrow \|f\|\Longrightarrow \|f_n-f\|\rightarrow 0$ for some norm $\|\cdot\|$ which in general does not stand.

Answer (score 0):

There will not be a continuous optimum, at least for $d = 1$. Assume that we have a solution $g$ --- we will see how to improve upon it. Write $C = C_1 + C_2 + C_3$ for the three terms of the functional.

Let $i$ be such that sign$(g(x_i)) \neq$ sign$(g(x_{i+1}))$. For concreteness, we assume that $g(x_i) > 0$, and that $\int_a^bgdx \geq 0$ (the other cases can be handled similarly). Let $(a,b) = (x_i,x_{i+1})$.

What does $g$ look like on this interval? Typically, it will be decreasing from $g(a)$ to $g(b)$, in which case $C_3(g) = g(a) - g(b)$. However, it could be that $\bar{g} := \max_{[a,b]}g(x) > g(a)$, in order to make $\int_a^bfdx$ sufficiently large (to help make $\int_\Omega f dx = 0$). In this case we will have $C_3(g) = (\bar{g} - g(a)) + (\bar{g} - g(b))$. Note that we will never have $\min_{[a,b]}g(x) < g(b)$, or $g$ could be improved.

We let $f = g$ everywhere except on $(a,b)$, so $C_1(f) = C_1(g)$. We let $k > 0$ be a large positive number, and construct $f$ on $(a,b)$ like this: i) grow linearly with rate $k$ until reaching $\bar{g}$, ii) stay constant for a time $h$, iii) decrease linearly with rate $k$ to 0, iv) stay 0, v) decrease linearly with rate $k$ to $g(b)$ at the end of the interval. Given $k$, we can always choose $h$ so that $\int_a^b f dx = \int_a^b g dx$. (In the case where $\bar{g} \leq g(a)$ step i) becomes void, and in the case $\int_a^bgdx = 0$ step ii) becomes void.)

The construction obviously gives $C_3(f) = C_3(g)$. But as $k$ increases, $C_2(f) = \int_a^b |f| dx$ will decrease downwards towards $\int_a^b f dx$, which contradicts the optimality of $g$.

The "problem" is that $C(f)$ does not penalise higher derivatives, which the construction above exploits. From a statistical learning perspective, this is usually solved by restricting the minimization of $C$-like functionals to some class of functions (the simplest examples would be ridge or lasso regressions).

Comment: What do you mean by answer is "no". You mean the solution is not unique? or Do you mean solution does not exist in this space? If so in which space the solution exist?

Comment: And do you suggest infimum of $C(f)$ is same in all situations? As I stated earlier comments, I am not worried even if the minimum value not being attained, but I am fine as long as the infimum is not trivial.

Comment: Yes, I mean that there cannot be an optimal continuous function (because if you show me a candidate, the construction will improve on it for sufficiently high $k$). I very much suspect that the infimum will be trivial, in some appropriate sense... The reason you can't get a continuous solution is that the optimization will "fit the data too much".

Comment: Its perfectly fine if the optimum solution is not continuous, so lets say the solution lies in a different space, I want to know what is that space?

Comment: Think about the simple $N=2$ example in the comments to the OP. The optimum will be $-\alpha I_\delta  +\alpha I_{1-\delta}$ for some number $\alpha>0$, where $I_x$ is the indicator function for $x$.

Comment: I don't agree this is the optimal. $C_3$ can be reduced right?

Comment: Yeah I should have said "optimum" --- if you give me any candidate solution, I will give you back an improved version, with the same $C_3$ as yours. As we iterate this procedure, the resulting solutions will look more and more like $f = -\alpha I_\delta + \alpha I_{1-\delta}$, even though $C_3(f)$ itself will be infinite.

Comment: I contradict that it looks like the indicator you have mentioned.

Comment: hm, yeah actually you are right. I agree that it will not tend to 0 on the "outside" $(0,\delta)$ and $(1-\delta,1)$. This seems to me like a sort of boundary artefact though, rather than a useful property of an optimum...

Comment: Why do you want to make it go to zero all together in $(0,\delta)$ and $(1-\delta,1)$. making this you might reduce $C_2$ but you are increasing $C_3$ aren't you. So the solution lies in an appropriate trade off between $C_3$ and $C_2$. The solution do not look like the indicator you mentioned right?

Comment: But your example on OP, where you choose points $0$ and $1$ (border) is pretty good corner case which needs to be eliminated. I should make points lie only in interior.

Comment: If you think its a boundary artifact, try choosing $3$ points that lie in interior. You will not end up with an indicator function.

Comment: This might be cheating, but adding the point $(1/2,0)$ to the $N=2$ example seems to change nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57887/discussion-between-svangen-and-rajesh-dachiraju).